# Running adb commands within app gives Permission denied

Tags: android

I am building an app which trying to execute some commands such as "top" and others.
i am working on android 7.0.
i try this code in older android versions but when i try it on the nougat i get the following error of Permission denied:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
              Process: com.example.matant.cmdlineapp, PID: 7662
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb shell top": error=13, Permission denied
                  at com.example.matant.cmdlineapp.MainActivity$RunningTopCommand.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:88)
                  at com.example.matant.cmdlineapp.MainActivity$RunningTopCommand.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:36)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
               Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb shell top": error=13, Permission denied
                  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:983)
                  at com.example.matant.cmdlineapp.MainActivity$RunningTopCommand.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:62)
                  at com.example.matant.cmdlineapp.MainActivity$RunningTopCommand.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:36) 
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
               Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
                  at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:133)
                  at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:128)
                  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:964)
                  at com.example.matant.cmdlineapp.MainActivity$RunningTopCommand.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:62) 
                  at com.example.matant.cmdlineapp.MainActivity$RunningTopCommand.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:36) 
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

the code i am executing is:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Execution en BackGround
        Log.d("BACKGROUND", "START");
        Log.d("BACK PARAM 0", params[0]);
        //Log.d("BACK PARAM 1", params[1]);

        try {
            // Executes the command.
            //Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb version");
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("adb shell top");
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            // Reads stdout.
            // NOTE: You can write to stdin of the command using
            //       process.getOutputStream().
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            int read;
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.append(buffer, 0, read);
                Log.d("reader val: ",output.toString());
                publishProgress(output.toString());
            }
            reader.close();

            return null;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205565)

> /sys and /proc are well known for leaking side channel information
>   about processes, information which can be used to infer state about
>   the processes. For instance, it's been documented for years that /proc
>   access can be used to monitor for app launching, enabling phishing
>   attacks.

So, with the release of N, dev team had intentionally restricted access of `/sys` and `/proc`. If I'm not mistaken, adb `top` command also solely relies on the reading of `/proc`'s states. This is, I presume, therefore not possible to perform `top` command through `ProcessBuilder` without being encountered the permission denied error starting from Android N.