# Detect current running application in Android Nougat 7.+ version

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, foreground, android-7.0-nougat

Android team changed their approaches to get current running applications from time to time. I am able to get current running applications upto Marshmallow 6.0 version but i want to ask that how can i get these in Nougat 7.0 version?
 Is there anyway to do that? Please guide towards solutions. I have searched a lot but could find any appropriate way to that.

Thanks

Comment: how to get current running applications on Android 6.0??

Comment: This would be helpful: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager

Comment: Thanks!
And i think i found a solution for android 7+: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16691633/938427

Comment: Updated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104739/running-adb-comands-within-app-gives-permission-denied
No Ways on android 7 :( (Don't run commands using Process: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb shell ps | grep": error=13, Permission denied)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer: no, you can't.

Long answer: you can't get the running process but you can retrospectively see what *was* running through the [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) (with the appropriate permissions, of course). The reason you can't get the running process is that Android have locked down the permissions of `/proc`

Comment: thanks for response. can you add any reference for AppUsageManager  to achieve this task?

Comment: Sorry got the name slightly wrong it's https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html

Comment: Follwed this: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager . and it worked for me

Comment: this isn't true. this app works perfectly on Nougat https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.taskmanager

Comment: @deviant you wrong. I tried open a game (no services in game). This app doesn't work truly.

Comment: As @Usman Rana said, his solution is still working on android 8.0.

Comment: I tested the task manager app mentioned by @deviant and as he said it is working on OS 7 but it fails to detect processes on OS8

Comment: Wow, these restrictions are terrible.

Comment: @Ryan there are apps like AppLocker and GalleryLocker that can detect a running app even in android 7.0 , you can find them in playstore,that means its surely possible through UsageStatManager but the question is how